# Getting error while running npm start after installing react JS

Tags: node.js, reactjs

[Error while running npm start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rspm8.png).Getting this error while running npm start command

Comment: please check your package.json file, the start script is missing

Answer (score 0):

This problem can occur from 3 things:

1. You don't have a `start` script in your `package.json`
2. Your project does not contain a `server.js` file
3. You added a second `script` key in the `package.json` file

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ' npm start ' to run your code, your packaje.json file must contain start script. Something like this.

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "node app"
  }
```